# Delayed Execution In VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, timer

I am in need to delay the execution of a line of code, say, by 5 seconds. But by doing

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`

the whole UI hangs and I don't want that to happen. Because I want to be able to display something in a Window that a user will be able to see. Does anyone know of an alternative of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use could use an Timer that executes once after 5 seconds. In WPF you will normally use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

```
dispatcherTimer = New Threading.DispatcherTimer()
AddHandler dispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf dispatcherTimer_Tick
dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0,0,5)
dispatcherTimer.Start()

Private Sub dispatcherTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  dispatcherTimer.Stop();
  '' Your code to be executed after 5 seconds
End Sub
```